# conda install packages for all user error The channel is not accessible or is invalid

Tags: python, conda

I installed anaconda python 3.6 in Windows Server (Windows 7 Enterprise) for all users, updated .condarc file to avoid company proxy firewalls. But when I try to install packages, it keeps on giving me error message as below:

[image]

[image]

I installed in my own laptop for me only (NOT all users) and updated .cnodarc file the same way, no issue to install packages via conda.

Could you anybody tell me why it is not working in server for all users? I did open 'Anaconda Prompt' with option 'Run as administrator'.

thank you

Comment: 1. It might be the proxy issue. disable the proxy and install.
2. try other channels like conda, pip, or direct download from PYPI.

Comment: We had a similar issue in our company and could only resolve it by installing a local cntlm proxy to handle authentication with the firewall

Comment: I think this is more appropriate for ServerFault. Also, people there will be a bit more security conscious. On the face of it, I find the idea of combining running Conda as an admin with not using SSL worrisome.